# stdout error not properly reported [Java System.out]

Tags: java

Here's a MWE:

```
class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Testing");
    if (System.out.checkError())
      System.exit(1);
  }
}
```

with `java Test >&-` exits with status 0.

Here is the console output:

```
% javac Test.java
% java Test >&-     
% echo $?
0
```

I expected a `1`.

```
% java --version
openjdk 21.0.2 2024-01-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 21.0.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 21.0.2, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Edit: to re-phrase the question, why am I getting a 0 and not a 1 for the return code (it should be reporting the error)?

Comment: What error do you mean when you say "I expected the error to be detected."?

Comment: I mean that I do not get an error @OldDogProgrammer . I will include output

Comment: [`PrintStream#checkError`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html) simply *"Flushes the stream if it's not closed and checks its error state."* - this returns `true` if *"if and only if this stream has encountered an IOException, or the setError method has been invoked"* so ... I'm kind of weird out over why you're trying to use it and what you're expecting to happen

Comment: I'm expecting it to report write errors if it can't actually write to stdout @MadProgrammer. This is just a MWE.

Comment: I don't think this is a Java issue. I suspect it has something to do with how your O/S is trying to interpret `& -`.  Try this:  create a file `foo.txt`, and make it read only. Then try `java test > foo.txt`

Comment: That gives `zsh: permission denied: foo.txt` @OldDogProgrammer

Comment: And the result of  `echo $?`

Comment: 1. But this is not Java @OldDogProgrammer. I'd like to be able to see if a write fails within Java. For this, the shell can tell that it's not able to write to the file when it tries to open it for writing before the `execve` call, so it never even executes the Java program. The other one, it should close stdout before invoking the Java program, so Java should detect it.

Comment: Yes, that detects it @OldDogProgrammer. But there is something subtle going on here. It detects that because we close the top-level Java Object stream, but not when the lower lvl file descriptor is closed before being handed off. Does my code example give 1 or 0 for you?

Comment: Is the question actually asking, why executing Test.class with a closed output stream produce error code 0? Whereas it should be 1?

Comment: Yes @moyu-sharo

Comment: I got the same results you did. Try this:  Add a `\n` to your output line:  `System.out.println("Testing\n");`.  Or, add  `System.out.flush();` following that line.

Comment: Still 0 @OldDogProgrammer

Comment: Hmmm  ... I get `1` when I try it with that change. I'm using Java `openjdk version "11.0.21" 2023-10-17`

Comment: I'm using `openjdk 21.0.2 2024-01-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 21.0.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 21.0.2, mixed mode, sharing)`

Comment: I saw that in the question.  If the inclusion / exclusion of the `\n` or `close ()` makes a difference in one version of Java and not the other, is that an indication this is a result of a bug in Java?  

If the result you get is what is supposed to happen, then it could be a bug in Java 11 that has been fixed?